# How to refer a particular TD in the first row of TBODY and change the class of the same row using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a HTML table like this

### HTML

```
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    <tr class="item">
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>Action</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="item">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John Collins</td>
    <td>9089898989</td>
    <td><button>Save</button></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Janine Godwin</td>
    <td>Janine Godwin</td>
    <td>43433434</td>
    <td><button>Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    </table>
```

I would like to remove the last TD (the button) in the first row inside the tbody tag and change the same row's class from 'item' to 'sample'. How can I do it with Jquery ?

Comment: One option is to give it a name or id. Is the number of td in a tr always going to 4? In that case, you can use nth-child selector

Comment: There is a jquery selector to refer the first row of a html table. I would like to solve this issue with that. Hopefully that is an efficient way to achieve this.!

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you just want the code?

Comment: @Bala.C Is the number of td in a tr always going to be 4?

Comment: I did tried many ways but I couldn't achive it, It could be helpful if i can get a piece of code to understand this

Comment: @AmitBhargava Yes, the TD is going to be four as the number of rows will be changed

Comment: Show us what you've tried already.

Comment: In that case once you get the first tr, use nth-child to get the fourth td. There are plenty of examples available for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Get the table:](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
   `$('#myTable')`
2. [Get the `<tbody>`:](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)
   `$('#myTable > tbody')`
3. [Get the first row in the `<tbody>`:](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)
   `$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first')`
4. Change that row's class [from `'item'`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) [to `'sample'`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):
   `$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first').removeClass('item').addClass('sample')`
5. [Get the last `<td>` in the first row in the `<tbody>`:](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)
   `$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first > td:last')`
6. [Remove that last `<td>`:](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
   `$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first > td:last').remove()`

Put it all together:

```
$('#myTable > tbody > tr:first')
    .removeClass('item')
    .addClass('sample')
    .children('td:last')
    .remove();
```

Comment: Edited one last time. I think it does everything you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you ask, but I recommend you to read Jquery's documentation.

```
$('tbody tr.item:first')
    .attr('class', 'sample')
    .find('td button').text('change me')
```

First part gets the row you want, second part changes the class, and third part finds the button and changes it (although, you didn't mention how do you want to change it).